# ANDROID activity force stop on restart

Tags: android, android-activity, restart, oncreate, onresume

I've looked through a lot of other threads about this but haven't had any luck yet with their solutions.
When I launch my app for the first time, I noticed that onResume is being called after onCreate. (not sure why)
My problem is when I try to run the application for the second time. Neither onCreate nor onResume get called, it just sits there.
ALso, I have these setting set in my manifest:

```
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true" 
android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
android:noHistory="true"
```

If I ever want to run my app more than once, I have to go into settings->applications->app-name->force-close

(I don't have access to look for any loops or bad bugs that might be causing the sticking because I'm using a library with it's own threads.)

Is there a way I can fix this?

Comment: "My problem is when I try to run the application for the second time. Neither onCreate nor onResume get called, it just sits there." How do I make the app really start from scratch when you run it?

Comment: Did you try cleaning your project?

Comment: just tried cleaning it. It didn't help either.

Comment: Did you put finish() in onBackPressed?

Answer (score 4):

Call `Process.sendSignal(Process.myPid(), Process.SIGNAL_KILL);` in your onDestroy method. This is not good but the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way android [manages the activities](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle). If you want your activity go through whole life cycle, call explicitly its [`finish()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) method.

Comment: I already tried putting finish() in both onStop and onPause but it didn't help. I'm not entirely convinced that they were even being called.

Comment: To make sure they are called add a breakpoint to them or print some message within them with `Log.e(String, String)`, for example

Comment: Set `android:clearTaskOnLaunch` to "false" and see what you get. And it would be nice if you provide a source code of the activity which is not recreated after calling its finish() method.